# Proving that there exists a sequence in $S$ such that $x_n$ converges to $\sup S$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am attempting to show that there is a sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ in $S$ such that $x_n$ converges to $a$, where $a = \sup S$ and $S$ is contained in the set of all reals.

Since $a = \sup S$, given $\epsilon > 0$ and that $x_n$ is in $S$, we know that $a-\epsilon < x_n \leq a$ since $a$ is a least upper bound by def'n of a supremum.  I do not know where to go from applying the def'n of supremum.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Any additional assumptions about $S$? Nonempty? Bounded from above?

Comment: We can assume that S is bounded from above.

Answer (score 4):

Well, we have two cases:

**Case 1: $a<\infty$**. In that case, take a sequence $x_n$ such that
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:a-\frac{1}{n}<x_n<a$$
(there is such $x_n$ for each $n$, due to the definition of supremum). Prove that this sequence converges to $a$.

**Case 2: $a=\infty$**. In that case, take a sequence $x_n$ such that
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:x_n>n$$
and continue similarly

Comment: You are missing the case 3: $a=-\infty$. Though in that case there of course is no such sequence.

Comment: Since the supremum of a set cannot be $-\infty$, it is irrelevant.